# Set entire page to black and White

Tags: html, css, colors, css-filters

I managed to accomplish high-contrast with invert css functionallity see (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/).

Now I need to see an entire site in *black and white*, **not grayscale**. Maybe there's a combination of this functions to make the effect I need? I've already tried contrast(100) grayscale(1); but it affects badly the letters (yo can't read them).

Answer (score 11):

Add this grayscale class to your body:

```css
.grayscale-100 {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.colored {
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="colored">
  This div has a red background and blue font color!
</div>
<div class="grayscale-100">
  <div class="colored">
    This div has the same style as the above, but its parent has the grayscale class!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png

Comment: Setting that style to body still wouldn't desaturate the body background, at least in Chrome 84. However, you can `<html style='filter: grayscale(100%);'>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this. The closest effect that I could achieve without the entire image becoming black was   `-webkit-filter: brightness(650%) grayscale(100%);` and that was still fairly gray. It's possible that I'm missing a way, but I think the grayscale tool was intended to make what we normally call black and white, only gray colors. Contrast 100 and Grayscale 1 worked pretty decently for the image that I tested on. I think your best option here is to use that and use an element for the text that doesn't have that filter applied.